# Printing middle of a linked list in case of even number of elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I know how to print the middle of a given linked list by taking two pointers which move at different speeds. First pointer move by one whereas second pointer move by two positions. Now, in case the linked list contains even number of nodes, that is, let's say 4 nodes, then, which one will technically be the middle. Also, the condition that I am using in the while loop for printing is,

```
fastptr = head;
slowptr = head;

while (fastptr->next->next != NULL && slowptr->next != NULL)
{
    slowptr = slowptr->next;
    fastptr = fastptr->next->next;
}
```

In this case, if I run the above code manually once, then, the code will stop when the `slowptr` is at second node and `fastptr` is at 3 node. Is this correct?

Comment: Your code will crash if `fastptr->next == NULL`.

Comment: Try it with some different cases and see what happens.

Comment: Are you asking which one your code **will** say is in the middle?  Or which one your code **should** say is in the middle?  The first is easy enough to determine.  The second is your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That it would be more clear and visible consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter the size of the sub array less than or equal to "
                  << N << " (0 - exit): ";

        size_t n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        if ( N < n ) n = N;

        size_t i = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n && ++j < n && ++j < n; ) i++;

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << a[j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }       
}
```

Its output is

```
Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
4

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
3

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
3

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 6
0 1 2 3 4 5 
2

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 5
0 1 2 3 4 
2

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 4
0 1 2 3 
1

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 3
0 1 2 
1

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 2
0 1 
0

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 1
0 
0

Enter the size of the sub array less than or equal to 10 (0 - exit): 0
```

So you can see yourself what element will be outputed when there are even or odd elements in the array.

How to rewrite the code for a list?

It can look the following way

```
node *slowptr = head;

for ( node * fastptr = head; 
      fastptr  && ( fastptr = fastptr->next ) && ( fastptr = fastptr->next ); )
{
    slowptr = slowptr->next;
}
```

This loop can be written even simpler if you will check before the loop that `head` is not equal to `NULL`

For example

```
node *slowptr = head;

if ( slowptr )
{
    for ( node * fastptr = head; 
          ( fastptr = fastptr->next ) && ( fastptr = fastptr->next ); )
    {
        slowptr = slowptr->next;
    }
}
```

As for the loop you showed then it is wrong

```
while (fastptr->next->next != NULL && slowptr->next != NULL)
```

`fastptr` and `fastptr->next` each can be equal to NULL. So the code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: The example that you gave mostly takes the n/2th element as the middle element (1 based indexing). Is that always true? Therefore, if number of nodes are 4, then the 2nd node is the middle node (1 based indexing)?

Comment: @John Lui It corresponds to expression ( N + 1 ) /2 that is when N is odd for example is equal to 3 then the second element will be outputed.

Comment: Oh! Right. Got it. So `(n+1)/2` is taken as the standard expression, right?

Comment: @John Lui See the program output. It demonstartes clear the approach: which element will be the middle one. I specially wrote this program.

Comment: @John Lui Yes if to count elements starting from 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, in case the linked list contains even number of nodes, that is, let's say 4 nodes, then, which one will technically be the middle?

Could be:

- the second one
- the third one
- neither, even length lists have no middle

... Depending on your specific definition of "middle". Refer to your assignment for the correct interpretation, or use whatever meaning is most convenient if it doesn't specify.

> In this case, if I run the above code manually once, then, the code will stop when the slowptr is at second node and fastptr is at 3 node. Is this correct?

Yes. (Assuming by "3 node" you mean "the third node" and not "the fourth node", which is what it would be if you're using a zero-based indexing system)

Answer (score 1):

You could choose 2nd or the 3rd node to be middle(if number of nodes are 4).But most of the times you'll see second node being treated as middle node.You can see the following code as your code might crash for e.g. if there are 3 nodes.After one iteration of the loop,`fastptr` will be pointing to last node and `fastptr->next->next` will crash.

```
 fastptr=head;
 slowptr=head;
 while(fastptr->next!=NULL)//ie continue until fastptr is at lastnode
 {
    fastptr=fastptr->next;
    if(fastptr->next==NULL)//ie last node
    break;
    fastptr=fastrptr->next;
    slowptr=slowptr->next;
  }
  //slowptr is pointing to middle node.
```

EDIT:Do check if list is empty beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

1) For those who are visiting this question now ,
if you consider no of elements =4

- if you consider 2 as middle element 
  then condition should be

  ```
   while(fast_ptr->next->next != head)
  ```
- if you consider 3 as middle element , then condition should be

  ```
   while(fast_ptr != head)
  ```

2) Also for odd elements condition is :

```
 while(fast_ptr->next != head)
```

So together 1) and 2

```
// for 2 as middle element
while(fast_ptr->next != NULL && fast_ptr->next->next != NULL)
{
   fast_ptr = fast_ptr->next->next;
   slow_ptr = slow_ptr->next;
 }
 printf("The middle element is [%d]\n\n", slow_ptr->data); `
```

or

```
// for 3 as middle element
while (fast_ptr != NULL && fast_ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        fast_ptr = fast_ptr->next->next;
        slow_ptr = slow_ptr->next;
    }
    printf("The middle element is [%d]\n\n", slow_ptr->data);
```

Generally 2nd case , 3 as middle element is used.